# ASP.NET HTTPHandler Friendly URLs not working on POSTBACK on IIS 7 (But do work on development machine)

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, iis-7, httphandler, friendly-url

On an ASP.NET/vb.net Project, I'm using `httphandlers` in order to create Friendly URLs in a page, by including the following in `web.config`:

```
<add name="xSearch" verb="*" path="/x*" type="FriendlyURLs.xSearch"/>
```

This server transfers the user using:

```
HttpContext.Current.Server.Transfer("/xHandlers/search.aspx?friendlyURL=" & id)
```

Everything is working splendid on the local machine (Visual Studio 2010, ASP.NET).

However, on the server itself, using IIS 7, friendly URLs works, but postback doesn't.

i.e. if there're controls (buttons, etc), instead of running their sub, they redirect to
`/xHandlers/search.aspx?friendlyURL=xxxxxxxx`

Any clues?

Answer (score 0):

Well, since I didn't get any replies...

What I did in this case was to workaround it with clientside js.